# Vuejs Testing app in web server

Tags: vue.js

Locally on my computer, I'm able to run `npm run serve` to test out my app. However, what if I wanted to do the same on my server? Where should I point my domain to?

Or whenever I want to test on my server, do I have to run `npm run build` and point my domain to `/dist`?

I'm asking because if I'm on a different computer, I don't want to have to clone the project every time and install npm and stuff to make it work. This way I would only need to have access to a terminal to test my app out wihout doing `npm run build` every time I make a change.

Answer (score 1):

You must be talking about `vue-cli`. Indeed, when you `npm run build` the output of your application is in `/dist`. You would serve the `index.html` from here.

It would be best to put a web server in front of it, declare the location to serve the assets from (the same as the root path, I'd imagine) and then you're off to the races.

However, you can also just use [ngrok](https://ngrok.com/) and setup some port forwarding on your local router. This will make it available publicly as well if you just want to preview things.

Answer (score 0):

You want run Vue-Cli on Server, you do ways after or you see:[Deploy a VueJS App with DigitalOcean](https://medium.com/@Web_Bailey/deploy-a-vuejs-app-with-digitalocean-fd6e7af07e40),[How To Set Up a Node.js Application for Production on CentOS 7](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-set-up-a-node-js-application-for-production-on-centos-7)

```html
step:1: install nodejs on Sever
step:2: install vue-cli (version 2 or 3)
step:3:cd to project, you run command: npm run build
step:4: you need install nginx on server
step:5: sudo nano /etc/nginx/nginx.conf, you edit the following:
server{
 listen 80;
 server_name domail.com 
 root /var/www/project-vue-cli/dist;
 index index.html index.htm index.php
 location / {
  try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
 }

}

step:6: you restart nginx: sudo systemctl restart nginx
step:7: you can open domain
```